# how do I fix this problem I'm having with findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, updates

Trying to update mongodb doc using `findOneAndUpdate` method

tried looking up the doc in various ways and reformating the update in different ways

```
router.put(
  "/edit",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("name", "Name is required")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
      check(
        "password",
        "Please enter a password with 8 or more characters"
      ).isLength({ min: 8 })
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.status(404).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { email, password, name } = req.body;

    const update = {
      email,
      password,
      name
     };

    const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);

    update.password = bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    try {
      const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user: req.user.id },
        { $set: update },
        { new: true, upsert: true }
      );
      res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

I want it to return the updated user but I keep catching an error and return 500.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: message: 'Path "user" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`.',
  name: 'StrictModeError',
  isImmutableError: false,
  path: 'user'

Comment: sorry should have posted that in the question too. I'll edit it to include error message

Comment: Look like the filter should be `{ _id: req.user.id }` instead of `{ user: req.user.id }`

Comment: that returned a new error.   message: 'Cast to string failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" at path "password"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"Promise { <pending> }"',
  kind: 'string',
  value: Promise { <pending> },
  path: 'password',
  reason: undefined
}

Comment: got it i needed to have the await keyword infront of my bcrypt functions and filter by _id thank you!!

Comment: whats the differance between hashSync and hash?

Comment: hashSync is synchronous and hash is asynchronous. More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#sync

Comment: I just noticed in the comments that you have resolved the issue, if so I can remove the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bcrypt.genSalt and hash methods return promise, so you need to await.

Also I changed to findOneAndUpdate  to findByIdAndUpdate which I think is clearer in this case.

Can you try with this code?

```
router.put(
  "/edit",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("name", "Name is required")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
      check(
        "password",
        "Please enter a password with 8 or more characters"
      ).isLength({ min: 8 })
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.status(404).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { email, password, name } = req.body;

    const update = {
      email,
      password,
      name
    };

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

    update.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    try {
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, update, {
        new: true,
        upsert: true
      });
      res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```